# How do I stop execution at the middle of PHP script that return success status?

Tags: php

I am running the following php script via web browser:

```
<?php
  require_once("test.php");
  ....
  exit(0);
  ....
  require_once("test2.php");
  ....
?>
```

I am debugging my php script.  I want the script to stop execute some where at the line of "exit(0)".  However, the php doesn't execute successfully.  If I remove "exit(0)" then it works.

How may I stop the PHP script execution in the middle?

Comment: Why doesnt it execute successfully?

Comment: does the codes after `exit(0);` required for a successful execution?

Comment: Could you provide the code inside the test.php and test2.php files for further reference and also clarify why is the script not working properly?

Comment: I am changing the LocalSettings.php of mediawiki to perform some task.  If I add exit(0) in the file, the php script stop working even though there is no error in the script.

Answer (score 2):

For the only purpose of debugging you can use the die() method so you will have

```
<?php
  require_once("test.php");
  ....
  die("killing the execution");
  ....
  require_once("test2.php");
  ....
?>
```

But you must remember that the code after the die will not be executed. The only way to "pause" the execution of a PHP is by using a debugger like **xdebugger** or **Zend_Debugger**